# Oracle E-Business Suite Change Default Browser

Tags: java, erp

We are using an app on Oracle E-Business Suite. When I click the upload a file button on the Java form Chrome opening by default. I set default browser to Microsoft Edge on Windows settings, even removed Chrome but not worked. The app throwing a Windows error like "chrome not found" when I remove Chrome.

Comment: BTW - I would not have removed Chrome. Some old stuff you may have read [Microsoft Edge (Chromium) v83 and Later Releases Certified with EBS 12.2 and 12.1.3](https://blogs.oracle.com/ebstech/post/microsoft-edge-chromium-v83-and-later-releases-certified-with-ebs-122-and-1213) and PDF [Recommended Browsers for Oracle E-Business Suite Release 12](https://ufs.admin.cam.ac.uk/files/document_389422.1_latest.pdf)